# how to use maps fragment in navigation drawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

how to use fragment maps in navigation drawer? I am trying to use but the error, so I possessed three chronological list that contains the display maps, I created two more yet or is empty. when I opened the first road maps well after I select the list view both appear blank activity was not a problem, and when I want to go back to the case where the application maps directly out ..

```js
public class CreateFragment extends Fragment {
 
 
 public CreateFragment() {
  
    
  
  
 }

  
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create, container, false);

  return rootView;
 }

}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
       
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

```html
![my LogCat][1]


    10-16 12:16:46.080: E/dalvikvm(1007): Could not find class 'gpq', referenced from method gpr.a
10-16 12:16:46.090: E/dalvikvm(1007): Could not find class 'gpq', referenced from method gpr.a
10-16 12:16:46.090: E/dalvikvm(1007): Could not find class 'gpq', referenced from method gpr.a
10-16 12:16:48.980: E/dalvikvm(1007): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.location.internal.ParcelableGeofence', referenced from method gls.a
10-16 12:17:06.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1007): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-16 12:17:06.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1007): Process: com.Zen.gethere, PID: 1007
10-16 12:17:06.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1007): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
10-16 12:17:06.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
10-16 12:17:06.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
10-16 12:17:06.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
10-16 12:17:06.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
10-16 12:17:06.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):  at com.Zen.gethere.CreateFragment.onCreateView(CreateFragment.java:43)
10-16 12:17:06.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):  at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
10-16 12:17:06.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
10-16 12:17:06.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
10-16 12:17:06.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
10-16 12:17:06.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
10-16 12:17:06.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
10-16 12:17:06.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-16 12:17:06.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-16 12:17:06.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-16 12:17:06.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
10-16 12:17:06.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-16 12:17:06.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-16 12:17:06.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
10-16 12:17:06.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
10-16 12:17:06.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-16 12:17:06.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1007): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #6: Duplicate id 0x7f080051, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
10-16 12:17:06.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):  at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4791)
10-16 12:17:06.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
10-16 12:17:06.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):  ... 19 more
```

```
enter code here
```

Comment: all questions that do not resolve this issue, because I am here only put fragment maps, not making coding errors in the class already!

Comment: Improve your question asking style and then ask questions. Can't understand what you really want. Also post your code, we are not magicians to guess about code from your error. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Follow this link and learn how to ask questions in SO.

Comment: I'm sorry I will fix my question sorry my english substandard

Answer (score 0):

You could try calling a method like OpenMap() from your navigation drawer in this section, where the method is located in your main activity with the following code:

```
public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
                OpenMap();
                break;




private void openMap() {
        double latitude = 32.715000;
        double longitude = -117.162500;
        String label = "Starting point";
        String uriBegin = "geo:" + latitude + "," + longitude;
        String query = latitude + "," + longitude + "(" + label + ")";
        String encodedQuery = Uri.encode(query);
        String uriString = uriBegin + "?q=" + encodedQuery + "&z=16";
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
```